# How to get an InputNode as String in SimpleXML (Java)

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

Is it possible to get the contents of an XML tag as a String in Java using Simple XML?
I'm trying to do it using a [Converter](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html). I can obatin `<tag1>` as an [InputNode](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/stream/InputNode.html) object, but there is no API to retrieve the contents as String. I could iterate the children with `InputNode.getNext()` and reconstruct the content by recursively retrieving name, attributes, values, etc... but I would never be sure that it would match the original XML.

Example:

```
<root>
  <tag1>
    <unknownTag>Unknown</unknownTag>
    <otherUnknownTag>
      <children1>hello</children1>
      <children2>bye</children2>
    </otherUnknownTag>
  </tag1>
  <tag2>
    ...
  </tag2>
</root>
```

I would like to retrieve the following contents of `<tag1>` as a String (and prevent deserialisation for all `<tag1>` children):

```
<unknownTag>Unknown</unknownTag>
<otherUnknownTag>
  <children1>hello</children1>
  <children2>bye</children2>
</otherUnknownTag>
```

The contents of `<tag1>` are not known at deserialisation time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is possible only partially. This is how far I've got:

```
public String getNodeAsString(InputNode node) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String value = node.getValue();
    if (value != null) {
        builder.append(value);
    }

    InputNode child = node.getNext();
    while (child != null) {
        builder.append("<").append(child.getName());

        for (String attribute : child.getAttributes()) {
            builder.append(" ")
                    .append(attribute)
                    .append("=\"")
                    .append(child.getAttribute(attribute).getValue())
                    .append("\"");
        }

        builder.append(">")
                .append(child.getValue())
                .append("</").append(child.getName()).append(">");

        value = node.getValue();
        if (value != null) {
            builder.append(value);
        }

        child = child.getNext();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

This kind of works but has two flaws:

- The order of attributes is not preserved because SimpleXML puts attributes to map and the attributes iteration is ordered in the same order as map keys.
- This cannot parse tags nested in direct child of the InputNode or at least I don't know how to get list of children of child node.